# Check only one Checkbox in a listview unchecking the previous one

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, adapter

I have a listview with checkboxes, i want that only one checkbox can be clicked (like radiobutton), but i don't know how, because all the checkboxes came from the item and have the same id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvIsN.jpg)

This is an example of my listview.

Can someone explain me a method for check the last Checkbox pressed and uncheck the previous one

in this image  you can find my code, as you can see i have only one id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4iLV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must use a radiogroup and within that radiogroup must be the checkboxes you need, if they are within the radiogroup automatically when selecting one the other is deselected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMGnT.png)

it is worth mentioning that the error that appears in the radiogroup is because I did not add the constrains

Comment: Please include the image and not link it

Comment: it won't work because although i should use radiogroup there is only one id. Now i wil update my questions for show better my problem